# Using 'continue with label' to reach an inner for loop

Tags: java, continue

```
while (true) {
    try {
        //create ImportantObject
        LoopToGoTo:
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
            //method in here throws the exception
            //ImportantObject is used in here.
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //report error
        continue LoopToGoTo;
    }
}
```

I would like to continue at a loop that is inside the try catch block. Is this possible?

EDIT: Sorry, I was not clear on why I couldn't move the try catch to inside the for loop. (edited snippet) If I put the try-catch inside the for loop, the calls inside won't be able to access the ImportantObject.. This is where I was stuck.

EDIT2: Okay, I resolved my problem, albeit without continue with label! I guess the answer to my question is a simple 'no'. Bad habits might be all over the place, but my assignments due in two hours. what can i say :D

```
//ImportantClass ImportantObject = null;
while (!ranOnce) {
    try {
        //create ImportantObject
        ranOnce = true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //report error
        continue;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
    try {
        //method in here throws the exception
        //ImportantObject is used in here.
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //report error
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have anything and it will continue to the for loop.

Comment: "If I put the try-catch inside the for loop, the calls inside won't be able to access the ImportantObject.. This is where I was stuck." - I don't understand - create ImportantObject, enter the for loop, then enter the try loop - that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, since you are already outside of the scope of the try block.

Why not just move the try catch inside the for loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
    try {
        //method in here throws the exception
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
    //report error
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to do this?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
          try {
            //method in here throws the exception
          } catch(Exception e) {
            //report error
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `continue;` will have same effect, what you want to achieve.