# SimGrid. Sending task by broken link

Tags: java, simgrid

In simulation `master` sends `task` to `worker` by sometimes broken link. In this case `task` will be lost, but `master` have to resend this task. I use such code for this:

```
boolean send = false;
    label : while (!send){
        try {
            task.send("Tier1_" + i);
            send = true;
            break;
        }catch (TransferFailureException e){
            waitFor(1);
            continue label;
        }
    }
```

But it still gives:

```
org.simgrid.msg.TransferFailureException
    at org.simgrid.msg.Task.receive(Native Method)
    at org.simgrid.msg.Task.receive(Task.java:271)
    at LHCb.Tier1.main(Tier1.java:35)
    at org.simgrid.msg.Process.run(Process.java:338)
[Tier1_7:LHCb.Tier1:(8) 10.000000] [jmsg/INFO] Unexpected behavior. Stopping now
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: I down voted the question because that's a Java issue, not a SimGrid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **do not mix named `continue` and Java exceptions**. Here is the longer answer.

If this is really your code, then simply try removing your label and your continue instruction. Your while loop should do the trick without it.

But I suspect that this is a reduced MWE of a larger project. In any case, your label is something ugly, and that's not something you should do in proper Java. I think you should rethink your whole code to remove that construct.

I don't find any definitive answer on the internet right now, but I think that Java does bad things if you exit a catch block with a goto like that (continue+label=goto). Here is a similar case: [Using 'continue with label' to reach an inner for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414378/using-continue-with-label-to-reach-an-inner-for-loop)